# Error trying to install pyodbc on ASUS ZenBook Laptop: Couldn not build wheels for pyodbc

Tags: python, command-prompt, pyodbc

I am trying to install pyodbc. I have python 3.12 and VS 2022. I have downloaded Microsoft C ++ Build Tools for VS. When I run "pip install pyodbc" I get the following error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyodbc
  Using cached pyodbc-4.0.35.tar.gz (273 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyodbc
  Building wheel for pyodbc (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.35.32215\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyodbc
Failed to build pyodbc
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyodbc, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I have python 3.12 and VS 2022. I have downloaded Microsoft C ++ Build Tools for VS.

Comment: Error 2 is "file not found".   Did you install the full Visual Studio or one of the Community editions?  Are you sure you picked the C++ compiler when you installed?

Comment: @TimRoberts: I think you might be confusing Windows error code 2 with an exit code 2 from a subprocess. I suspect the compiler has been found but is reporting an error: if the compiler wasn't there I'd expect an error containing `The system cannot find the file specified`. There are plenty of answers on SO reporting this error message because a developer missed a return statement from a function, or similar.

Comment: Are you genuinely using Python 3.12? At the time of writing, Python 3.12 hasn't been released yet, it's still in development, so I'm not surprised there are no binary wheels for pyodbc on Python 3.12. If you don't have to use Python 3.12, try downgrading to an earlier version.

Comment: @LukeWoodward That was it. I used 3.11 and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, the solution was to downgrade from Python 3.12 to Python 3.11.

As I write this, Python 3.12 has not been made generally available, only as a pre-release (3.12.0a6). It is therefore likely that the pyodbc maintainers have not built binary wheels for pyodbc for Python 3.12. With no binary wheel, the native part of pyodbc would have to be built from source, and that would require a C/C++ compiler and build tools. In this case, however, it seems a compiler error has been encountered building the package, so the package installation has failed.

What the precise compiler error is, and whether the error is in pyodbc or Python 3.12, I cannot say.